# Is there a software implementing Mozarts dice game?

Tags: music-composing

> A [..] "[musical dice game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musikalisches_W%C3%BCrfelspiel)" was a system for using dice to randomly 'generate' music from precomposed options. These 'games' were quite popular throughout Western Europe in the 18th century. Several different games were devised, some that did not require dice, but merely 'choosing a random number.'

[This web page](http://sunsite.univie.ac.at/Mozart/dice/) demonstrates the concept. I'm looking for a software that implements that. Even more great would be an advanced version

- with support for jazz voicings using common chord progression
- the option to specify the basic song part structure
- a feature for "re-dicing" sub-parts
- playback / export to midi
- export of chord progression to plain-text.

Answer (score 1):

There is a plug-in for Kodi (ex XBMC) with that name. And it plays random 1-minute waltzs.

Here is the link: [Mozart's Dice Game - Kodi plugin](http://kodi.wiki/view/Add-on:Mozart%27s_Musical_Dice_Game)